# Saving numpy array to txt file row wise

Tags: python, numpy, save

I have an numpy array of form

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

which I want to save to a .txt file such that the file looks like:

```
1 2 3
```

If I use numpy.savetxt then I get a file like:

```
1
2
3
```

There should be a easy solution to this I suppose, any suggestions?

Comment: Or you only dealing with 1D arrays?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If `numpy >= 1.5`, you can do:

> # note that the filename is enclosed with double quotes,
>       #  example "filename.txt"

```
numpy.savetxt("filename", a, newline=" ")
```

**Edit**

several 1D arrays with same length

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpy.array([4,5,6])
numpy.savetxt(filename, (a,b), fmt="%d")

# gives:
# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6
```

several 1D arrays with variable length

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
b = numpy.array([4,5])

with open(filename,"w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in (a,b)))

# gives:
# 1 2 3
# 4 5
```

Comment: What if a new identical array is to be added to the file, at next row. How to break the line first line and continue on the second line?

Comment: @PatrikT: If you have more than one 1D arrays you can just do `numpy.savetxt(filename,(a,b,c))`. It saves row wise. But they should have same size.

Comment: What if e.g. a is shorter than b and c? How do I save these 3 arrays row wise?

Comment: @PatrikT: If you have variable length arrays, `savetxt` is not much of help. It is possible to do but it gets uglier and beats the purpose I think. Just write them normally as [BioGeek](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9565547/843822) suggested in a loop. I'll edit my answer to include all those alternatives.

Comment: `newline=" "` will result in a trailing delimiter (space), which some programs don't accept (there must be strictly a new line at the end of the printing, rather than a space and then a new line).

Answer (score 26):

An alternative answer is to reshape the array so that it has dimensions `(1, N)` like so:

```
savetext(filename, a.reshape(1, a.shape[0]))
```

Comment: This is exactly what you need if you're dumping readings into a file where every reading is made up of N samples. Perfect answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])

with open(r'test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(" ".join(map(str, a)))
```

Answer (score 6):

I found that the first solution in the accepted answer to be problematic for cases where the newline character is still required. The easiest solution to the problem was doing this:

```
numpy.savetxt(filename, [a], delimiter='\t')
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but none of these answers solved the root problem of numpy not saving the array row-wise. I found that this one liner did the trick for me:

```
b = np.matrix(a)
np.savetxt("file", b)
```

Comment: Would you explain "array row-wise"?

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3]    
b = np.array(a).reshape((1,3))    
np.savetxt('a.txt',b,fmt='%d')
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may solve the problem at hand, more explanation is necessary to help future users of the site understand how to apply this solution to their situation.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Very very easy:
[1,2,3]

A list is like a column.

```
1
2
3
```

If you want a list like a row, double corchete:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]  --->    1, 2, 3
```

and

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]  ---> 1, 2, 3
                             4, 5, 6
```

Finally:

```
np.savetxt("file", [['r1c1', 'r1c2'], ['r2c1', 'r2c2']], delimiter=';', fmt='%s')
```

Note, the comma between square brackets, inner list are elements of the outer list

Answer (score 0):

The [`numpy.savetxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) method has several parameters which are worth noting:

> fmt : str or sequence of strs, optional
>       it is used to format the numbers in the array, see the doc for details on formating
>
> delimiter : str, optional
>       String or character separating columns
>
> newline : str, optional
>       String or character separating lines.

Let's take an example. I have an array of size `(M, N)`, which consists of integer numbers in the range (0, 255). To save the array row-wise and show it nicely, we can use the following code:

```
import numpy as np

np.savetxt("my_array.txt", my_array, fmt="%4d", delimiter=",", newline="\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

just

```
' '.join(a)
```

and write this output to a file.

Comment: That will give a `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int32 found`, so you must first convert to string before joining.

Comment: ' '.join(str(x) for x in a)