# Saving 1D numpy arrays of different sizes to txt file columnwise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Below is the illustration code

```
from pylab import *

 a = array([1,2,3])
 b = array([4,5])
```

What I want test.out has is

```
1 4
2 5
3
```

previously, people has given solution of store of 1D numpy arrays of different sizes to txt file rowwise: [Saving numpy array to txt file row wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565426/saving-numpy-array-to-txt-file-row-wise)

Then how to save them columnwise?

Of course you can use 
three array like this

```
 a = array([1,4])
 b = array([2,5])
 c=array([3])
```

and save them in row wise
however it is not a smart way, when there is a lot of 1D arrays.

Comment: you can convert them to string and use pandas.

Comment: Open a file, and write the numbers out line by line.  Use ordinary Python string formatting to create each line.  That is basically what `np.savetxt` does.

Comment: I will learn pandas later.@Colonel   savetxt only saves arrays with the same sizes @hpaulj

Comment: That's why I suggest doing your own write.  I mention `savetxt` to make it clear that a homespun writer is just as good - better if it handles your problem.  This is just an ordinary Python file write problem.

Comment: no need to write your own write ... pandas is just simplifying life a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

d  = dict(a=a, b=b)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').transpose().fillna('')

#   a  b
#0  1  4
#1  2  5
#2  3
```

And write in a csv (you do not want to write the index nor the column):

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: I am learning how to install pandas now, seemingly that .whl is difficult to install than numpy.exe etc.

Comment: you can directly install Anaconda https://www.continuum.io/downloads, it's python including most of the needed library (numpy, pandas, etc)

Comment: I succeeded to install it using pypi, but Why i got this 4 5 is the first column? 1 2 3 second? ...confused

Comment: Somehow, the sequence of columns is not fixed as a and b... Is it because  the pandas package is installed improperly?

Comment: what is your result? you can reorder the columns if needed.

Comment: my result is column 1 is 4, 5. column 2 is 1,2,3. While yours are correct, 1st column is 1,2,3, 2nd column is 4,5. very tricky!!!

Answer (score 2):

My answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34242952/901925 could be adapted to this case

3 arrays of different length; could be lists

```
In [715]: heights=np.array([40,50])
In [716]: widths=np.array([60,65,70])
In [717]: yrs=np.array([1995,1996,1997,1998])
```

use `itertools.zip_longest` to iterate through them, with a `fillvalue` where values are missing:

```
In [718]: for xyz in itertools.zip_longest(yrs,widths,heights,fillvalue=''):
    print('%-12s,%-12s,%-12s'%xyz)
   .....:     
1995        ,60          ,40          
1996        ,65          ,50          
1997        ,70          ,            
1998        ,            ,
```

to write to a file use:

```
In [719]: with open('temp.txt','w') as f:
    for xyz in itertools.zip_longest(yrs,widths,heights,fillvalue=''):
        f.write('%-12s,%-12s,%-12s\n'%xyz)
   .....:         
In [720]: cat temp.txt
1995        ,60          ,40          
1996        ,65          ,50          
1997        ,70          ,            
1998        ,            ,
```

(`itertools.zip_longest` in PY3, `izip_longest` in Py2).