# exporting different lists to .txt in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, export

I have a few lists which I all want to export to the same .txt file.

So far I only export 3 of the lists  using

```
my_array=numpy.array(listofrandomizedconditions)
my_array2=numpy.array(inputsuser)
my_array3=numpy.array(reactiontimesuser)
combined=numpy.column_stack([my_array,my_array2,my_array3])
numpy.savetxt(participantnumber + ".txt", combined, delimiter=" ", fmt ="%-12s")
```

This gives me an output like

```
CongruentPositief no input or wrong button no reactiontime
IncongruentNegPos no input or wrong button no reactiontime
```

Since this is quite hard to read I want to add a tab between all the different lists.

Also I want to add a few lists which aren't 192 elements long unlike the first 3, but then I get an error that every array has to be the same size. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why are you using arrays?  Why not lists and strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Especially if you are starting with lists (of strings) I don't see the point to using `numpy` arrays.

For a start just try printing values:

```
In [659]: conditions=['one','two','three']
In [660]: values=[1,2,3]
In [661]: other=['xxxx','uuuuuuu','z']
```

basic format

```
In [662]: for xyz in zip(conditions, values,other):
    print("%s,%s,%s"%xyz)
   .....:     
one,1,xxxx
two,2,uuuuuuu
three,3,z
```

refined with tab and fixed lengths:

```
In [663]: for xyz in zip(conditions, values,other):
    print("%-12s\t%-12s\t%-12s"%xyz)
   .....:     
one             1               xxxx        
two             2               uuuuuuu     
three           3               z
```

Next step is to open a file and write to that, instead of `print`.

It's column stack that requires equal length strings.  `savetxt` just creates a `fmt` string from your parameter (and the number of columns), and writes each `row` like I do.

---

```
In [667]: with open('temp.txt','w') as f:
   .....:     for xyz in zip(conditions,values,other):
   .....:         f.write('%-12s,%-12s,%-12s\n'%xyz)
   .....:         
In [668]: cat temp.txt
one         ,1           ,xxxx        
two         ,2           ,uuuuuuu     
three       ,3           ,z
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.