# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable when use of write.()

Tags: python, numpy

I've this error message `TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable` when y execute my .py.

It occur in:

```
file=open("results.txt","a")
    for i in ConcatRPH:
        for j in i :
        file.write(j)
    file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

ConcatRPH is  a large array about 2 million line by 3 column which containt floats  like `-0.00161894927736417`and i need to write them in a txt file. I don't know why I have this error ... Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure that you've got the indentation correct? And perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565426/saving-numpy-array-to-txt-file-row-wise) post discusses what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible reason is that `ConcatRPH` does not have the shape you think it has. So, most likely, the `i` you get from `for i in ConcatRPH` is a float, and you get an error on the following line. Print `i` to make sure.

However, if you really want to store a table to a text file (not doing it for practice), better use `numpy.savetxt`.

Comment: Great !  It work with the numpy.savetxt.  Thank you blue_note